# Create a simple int selection model with tapestry

Tags: tapestry

I need to make a select consisting of the options 1,2,3 ... 250.

```
<p>
<t:label for="quantity2" style="width:40%" />
<t:select  t:id="quantity2" t:model="literal:0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7" /> 
</p>
```

This code works but I want to have the numbers up to 250!

Thank you, and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [select component's documentation](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/Select.html) "When the model parameter is a string, it is split apart at the commas. When the model parameter is a List of Strings, each element is considered a selection option."

So, I suggest you use a list of strings:

TML

```
<t:select t:id="quantity2" value="selectedQuantity2" t:model="quantities" />
```

Java

```
public List<String> getQuantities() {
    // create a list of strings from "1" to "250"
}
```

Comment: It works :) Thank you :) I already tried with a list, but a list of integers.

Answer (score 0):

Change your select do this:

```
<t:select t:id="quantity2" value="selectedQuantity2" t:model="Quantity2Model" />
```

In your page class, do this

```
@Property
private SelectModel quantity2Model;

@Inject
SelectModelFactory smf;

void setupRender()
{
    List<int> values = new ArrayList<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 250; ++i)
    {
        values.Add(i);
    }
    quantity2Model = smf.create(values, "name");
}
```

*Warning:* I've never even heard of tapestry until I read your question, and I am not proficient in Java, so this is just based on my research from [here](http://tapestry.apache.org/using-select-with-a-list.html). Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work. It returns a null exception (with smf.create). I don't understand why it's so complex ! It's just a list of int...

Comment: I agree, it seems harder than I would expect.